# Creating new record in Aurelia -- error with JSON encoding?

Tags: javascript, json, aurelia

I'm creating an Aurelia app and it successfully pulls records from an API, edits and saves changes to individual records, and deletes individual records. However, I cannot seem to fix a problem with creating new records.

In **calendar.js**, I have the function newCalendar() which is called by a form button.

```
newCalendar() {
    this.selectedId = this.error = null;
    this.calendar = [];
    this.calendar.cal_name_tran = "New Calendar";
    this.calendar.cal_name_orig = "Nuevo Calendario";
    console.log(this.calendar);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.calendar));
    $('#edit_calendar').modal('show');
    $('#cal_name_orig').focus();
}
```

When I click the button, I get the following text in the console log:

`[cal_name_tran: "New Calendar", cal_name_orig: "Nuevo Calendario"]
[]`

The text "New Calendar" and "Nuevo Calendario" are successfully bound to the View in the Modal form.

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="cal_name_orig">Calendar name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cal_name_orig" placeholder="${'Calendar_Example_Name'&t}" value.bind="calendar.cal_name_orig & validate">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="cal_name_tran">Translated name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cal_name_tran" value.bind="calendar.cal_name_tran & validate">
    </div>
</form>
```

However, when I try to save the calendar using the following function, it sends an empty string, same as what is showing up in the second line of the console log (above).

```
saveCalendar() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.calendar));
    this.httpClient.fetch("/calendar/new", {
        method: 'put',
        body: json(this.calendar)
    });
}
```

Why does `JSON.stringify(this.calendar)` results in an empty array when `this.calendar` shows the values of the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the calendar to contain key-value pairs, you can make it an object (instead of array).

```
this.calendar = {};
```

`JSON.stringify` expects a valid JSON (can be an array then as well). In your example, although you are creating the `calendar` as an array, you are using it as an object.

If you want it to be an array, you will have to use the `push` method instead:

```
this.calendar = [];
this.calendar.push("New Calendar", "Nuevo Calendario");
```

Comment: Thank you!  I figured it had to be something obvious but didn't realize the difference between the brackets.  Do curly brackets always mean object, and square brackets always use array?

Comment: Yeap, exactly like this.

Answer (score 4):

No need to give this answer an upvote since the actual question has already been answered. I wanted to mention an issue with your code.

In your `newCalendar`function, you have two lines that use jquery to work with elements in your view:

```
$('#edit_calendar').modal('show');
$('#cal_name_orig').focus();
```

You're using IDs here. I wanted to point out that this is both unnecessary, and discouraged when using Aurelia. Instead of using IDs to reference the elements, you can use the `ref` custom attribute provided by Aurelia. The `ref` attribute allows you to create a reference to a DOM element as a property on your VM. Let's look at the `cal_name_orig` textbox:

```
<input type="text" 
       class="form-control" 
       id="cal_name_orig" 
       placeholder="${'Calendar_Example_Name'&t}" 
       value.bind="calendar.cal_name_orig & validate">
```

You can simply replace the `id` attribute with the `ref attribute:

```
<input type="text" 
       class="form-control" 
       ref="cal_name_orig" 
       placeholder="${'Calendar_Example_Name'&t}" 
       value.bind="calendar.cal_name_orig & validate">
```

and now this element is available in your VM using `this.cal_name_orig` (you might consider renaming this to match JS naming conventions). So instead of:

```
 $('#cal_name_orig').focus();
```

you can do:

```
  $(this.cal_name_orig).focus();
```

And now you don't have to worry about some other part of your application having a id naming conflict!

This isn't the only type of reference you can do. To learn more, check out our docs here: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-basics/5

Thanks!

Comment: I know you said you didn't need the upvote, but honestly that was VERY helpful!!!  Thanks for going above and beyond.